# Como saber se a pessoa já visitou outro site meu com cookies?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

Exemplo, eu tenho 2 domínios diferentes, gostaria de saber com cookies se ele já visitou antes, ou se já clicou em determinada coisa em meu outro site, ou seja, se ele já visitou meu site antes, clicou em uma coisa salvou o cookies la, quando ele ir pro outro site não precisar ver ou clicar novamente.

Sei fazer isso no mesmo domínio, mas em diferentes eu não sei.

Eu defino o cookie assim:

```
setcookie("cookiee","sim", time() + 172800,  $path = "/"); // 86400 = 1 dia, 172800 = 2 dias (SEGUNDOS)
```

E verifico assim:

```
<?php if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookiee'])): ?>
 Não tem
<?php else: ?>
 Tem
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Cara, acho que cookie é exclusivo do domínio, logo não dá pra ter acesso de outro domínio. Receio que terá que usar banco de dados.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mateus, infelizmente, **não** tem como acessar os cookies de outra página, nem como definir cookies para outra página.

O que você pode fazer é o seguinte:
Vamos supor que tem o domínio `a.com` e `b.com`. Quando o utilizador abre `a.com`, guarda um cookie para `a.com`, e, abre uma página de `b.com` (por exemplo, com um iFrame). Essa página de `b.com` (`savecookie.php`, por exemplo), guarda o cookie para a página `b.com`.

---

Exemplo Prático

**a.com/index.php**

```
<?php
setCookie("visited", "true", time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60); //O máximo de duração
?>
<iframe style="display:none" src="b.com/setcookie.php"></iframe>
```

**b.com/setcookie.php**

```
<?php
setCookie("visited", "true", time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
?>
```

Aí pode consultar o cookie de qualquer uma  das páginas. Me diga se não me fiz entender.